# Java - how to call an add() method in a different class

Tags: java, class, object, addition, indexoutofboundsexception

This is for homework, and I am becoming a little frustrated with how I can't figure out something so simple.

To simplify my code, I have 3 files right now: one class with an add() method I created among other things, one file that tests it (made by the prof), and one that creates the object (which I won't post, b/c its working). Here's the add() function.

**EDIT 2:** I'm going to add the method that prints the array, maybe that's the problem?

```
    public class Population {
      private Person[] pop = new Person[15];
      private int numPop = 0;    

      public void add(Person c){ // this object is created in another class, it works fine
        for(int i = 0; i < pop.length; i++){
          if(pop[i] == null) {
            pop[i] = c;
            numPop++;
          } else {}
        }

 public String listPeople(){
      System.out.println("Population with "+numPeople+" people as follows:");
      int i = 0;
      while (i<numPeople){
       System.out.println("A "+pop[i].getAge()+"year old person named "+pop[i].getName());
        i++;
//FYI the get methods are working fine and are in another file.
 } 
      return("");
      }
```

Then, I run the program in a test file to ensure it works, which was provided to us. Here's the part that isn't working

```
public class PopTestProgram{ // FYI the prof created this, I can't change this
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Population pop = new Population(15);

    pop.add(new Person(4, "Bob"));
    pop.add(new Person(25, "Kim"));
    // then adds 8 more people with different ages and names
    // then prints the people
```

It compiles, but when I run it, it just puts 10 of the last person into the array, then crashes saying there is a problem with the `"pop[i] = c;"` line. I simply cannot figure out what I need to change here.

I haven't received an email from the prof directly, so I thought I'd ask here.

Edit: Here's what it shows after printing out the last person 10 times. It is showing problems with other methods that I haven't completed yet though...

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at Population.removePerson(Population.java:49)
    at PopTestProgram.main(PopTestProgram.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: What is the exact exception you get?

Comment: yeah show the whole darn thing!

Comment: It looks like an error with what's being passed from the 'new Person(4, "Bob"));' line. Could you show the method, or at least show what the value of 'c' is at the time of the error?

Comment: I'll post the exception if you really want it, but I played around with my code and now it isn't showing me the exception I want to see... it is showing exceptions for different methods that I haven't totally completed yet.

Comment: This isn't the answer but instead of a `for` loop, you should use a `while` loop to find the index of the `null` value in `pop` and use that value *outside* of that loop. That way, once you find that index, you don't have to go through the rest of the array.

Comment: And the exception that you posted isn't referencing `add()` method at all so I don't know how that will help this problem...

Comment: sparky: exactly, it isn't saying there is a problem with add(). that's why I'm completely lost. I'm not a pro yet so I have no idea if it is just a problem with funny syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

In add(Person), you are not stopping when you add an item, so the first item you added is put in all cells in the array, then the rest won't go in at all, since there are no more null cells in array.  Break the loop when you find an empty location.

```
public void add(Person c) {
    for(int i = 0; i < pop.length; i++){
      if(pop[i] == null) {
        pop[i] = c;
        numPop++;
        break;
      }
      else {
        //.....
      }
   }
}
```

Could also just use numPop as the next location in the list, like:

```
public void add(Person c) {
    if (numPop < pop.length) {
       pop[numPop++] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: This didn't work :( It is printing the exact same thing. I'll add in the method that prints the array, maybe the problem lies there.

Comment: The problem is in removePerson.  Please include that method.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is coming in  at `Population.removePerson(Population.java:49)`, which is not related to add method. So I assume removePerson is the method to print the person.
While removing you are calling **one extra For loop**, make sure your iteration is **10** times only.

The `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`clearly tells the **removePerson** method is calling the **index -1** also (which doesnt exist causing ArrayIndexOufofBoundsException). The removePerson method should start from index 9 to index 0 (or viceversa) [10 iteration in total] and then stop out.

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this is not where the error is. That method is not yet whole, you're right, but the errors I'm trying to fix are happening before removePerson() even runs. That's why I mentioned that the exceptions will not be helpful :)

Comment: The exception trace says so: at Population.removePerson(Population.java:49). What is the code at line 49 in Population.java

Comment: Yeah i know that there is an error there. but it runs after add() and listPeople(), so it's totally irrelevant to the current problem. I could take out removePerson() and I would be having the same problem. That's what I meant.